# Single window application with 100% height and no scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am currently developing a web application using `jQuery`. 
The layout for the same goes as shown in the figure given below:

[image]

The orange color box at the very back should be 100% in height and width with some margin like 5px or so.

The logo and the tab-bar are placed as shown and are about 50px in height. But tab-bar should take size as shown with some margin.

The tab content should occupy the remaining height and should scroll for the contents it occupies.

Similar structure is required for the internal menubar and tab content.

Can anyone please suggest the layout method to employ?
Or how can I manipulate different heights/widths?

The requirement also suggests a responsive window i.e. the width/height to manipulate on resize.

Comment: Have you done any markup yet? if so post it.

Comment: That's like asking someone else to do your work! Get going, put what you can in a jsFiddle and then people will help you; but we're not here to do your work

Comment: I will post a markup put up .. @frenchie I was just asking for a general direction to work upon .. as in general idea .. not the whole code! .. I am stuck at the height manipulation thing!

This is a general jsFiddle I am struggling with right now: http://jsfiddle.net/4BR9s/376/

There the overflow: auto; doesnt seem to work on the contentBox. Can anyone please guide.

Comment: @cube : jsfiddle.net/4BR9s/376 There the overflow: auto; doesnt seem to work on the contentBox. Can you please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/B65D6/) I said I'd make.

As you'll see, I make use of jQueryUI for the "tabs" layout and simply "add" a few things.  The few things I "Add" are simple and the jQueryUI alreqady provides a strong CSS with which to manipulate to get desired result.  Also attached to that page is a theme-switcher, so you could see what it would look like using different jQueryUI Default Themes.

I'll try to explain the process as shortly as possible without being to vague.

### HTML

I first start with a basic page wrapper. Not too necessary, but it provides a nice "element" with which to work inside of and possibly make manipulations for page layout change in otherways in the future. For now it simply holds our page "padding" of 5px.  The HTML and BODY tags will be set to a default and should not be manipulated beyond that as height and other properties begin to take different meanings for these tags in different browsers.

I then place 2 divs inside this wrapper, again, these could be done without depending on your needs. I like these 2 divs and use this alot because it provides "vertical align -> middle" as one might expect. The first, parent, is a div with class `table`. This will have its `display` set to table to provide a "table-like" layout but still have the ability to do things like "round the corners" or, as in my case, set height! The second, child, is the same except it will have a class and style as `table-cell`, respectively. This allows us to set something like `vertical-align: middle;` and ensure that this element is in the vertical middle of the page/table element. Again, with your layout, this may seem unneccessary, but I don't know your full expected end result and I'm trying to give as much "fluid dynamics" to the page as possible.

Finally, I first insert the jQueryUI tabs HTML in their expected layout, with 2 small differences. I place our "logo" in a custom span tag just before the `ul`. I also take the `ui-tab-panel`(s) and place them in their own container. This helps us adjust the height of our tabs area as needed. I also gave this container overflow, so even tho overflow maybe hidden on the body, it's still available for the tabs. (see also: [small blog i wrote on jQueryUI Tabs](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html))

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div id="tabs">
                <span class="my-logo">
                    <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="logo here" />
                </span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="ui-tabs-panel-container">
                    <div id="tabs-1">
                        <<p> ... </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-2">
                        <p> ... </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-3">
                        <p> ... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

As I mentioned before, jQueryUI provides us with a strong CSS to work with already. As you might have noticed, I made use of some of this by using their predefined class names throughout the HTML.  This established things like `background`, `color`, and even `font-family` and more! Now that that is over with, let's layout our page mechanics first. As I mentioned, I give a very "direct" set of properties to `HTML` and `BODY`. This will help eliminate "Cross-browser-issues". I also provided a background color, tho you could set that at one of the children levels. This was done just to show you where HTML, BODY exist.

I then set our "frame" elements. `.page-wrapper` will provide our page wrapping, sizing will come from within, so there is no need to deal with it here. The `.table` and `.table-cell` provide display exactly as their name suggest. As previously mentioned, this provides a nice ability to maintain an element in the exact "center" of something, even vertically!

Now we manipulate our tabs and content. I use `#tabs` throughout to maintain "name-spacing". This will not only help with any "css overrides" on jQueryUI presets, but also helps keep page layout confusions to a minimum. This is always a good thing.

The first thing I manipulate is the placement and setting of our custom span for the logo. Then, of course, I have to change the `ul` to next to it. Thus I look at the CSS for the `ul`s class. If I open edit tools in a browser, I can see the ul is given the classname `ui-tabs-nav` and I can see it has a margin setting. If I play with the `margin-left` of this ul I can see that nothing is affected but the left side of the ul. PERFECT! Here is what I must manipulate to set our log in its "own space".

Finally, I simply set our tabs container (given custom class name, `ui-tabs-panel-container`, made to match jQueryUI) to have overflow, so that if any content exceeds our page height, it can still be scrolled within this element.

```
html, body {
    background-color: #ADDFFF;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
    padding: 5px;
}
.table { display: table; }
.table-cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
#tabs .my-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 2em;
    margin: .5em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2em;
}
#tabs .my-logo img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel-container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

### JS

Finally, the easy work. I write a function to set the height of our tabs content area, since it will be "filling" the rest of the page. This take a little thought, but not hard to figure out. With the function written, I simply add it to the window resize event and call that event right after. This way it's resized on load, thus giving us our "end height" for first view. I also establish the tabs, although not much work there since I'm just making "default tabs". Feel free to experiment, go wild!

```
//  the following will resize our tabs content area and account for all the spacing neccessary
function setContentHeight(e) { return $(window).innerHeight() - $(this).offset().top - 10; }  // -10 to account for padding

$(function() {  //  our on page load call
    $("#tabs").tabs();  //  establish tabs
    //  add ability to resize tabs content area on window resize, then call resize event
    $(window).resize(function(e) { $("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel-container").height(setContentHeight) }).resize();
})
```

As for the layout of tab content, it's all up to you and your imagination. Hopefully this will give you a good idea of where to get started though! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Blueprint CSS:

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Here's a very quick and dirty layout (not using blueprint CSS, just plain CSS), as a general guideline. It still needs work, but it could be used as a starting point:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   /* hide page scrollbars */
}

div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;    /* for debugging */
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

#header > div {
    height: 5%;
    float: left;
}

#logo {
    width: 23%;
}

#spacer {
    width: 1%; /* -1% for borders */
}

#tabbar {
    width: 75%;
}

#tabContent {

}

#tabContent > div {
    width: 100%;
}

#tabContentMenuBar {
    height: 5%;
}

#tabContentMain {
    min-height: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <div id="tabbar" class="fullWidth">Tab bar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabContent">
        Tab content
        <div id="tabContentMenuBar">Tab content - menu bar</div>
        <div id="tabContentMain">Tab content - main content</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! .. I put it up on a jsFiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/jNSb6/ .. See i am not able to put the height to auto-adjust with the whole screen .. Only that is the problem .. Thanks a lot though .. :)

Comment: Yea, I wouldn't quite suggest blueprint for what is wanted. Blueprint is nice, but its limitation is its dynamics. It's really great if you want an old skool 3 column look where your content fills the page on down, but not so good for "no scroll" single window kind of stuff. For that I suggest a use of jQueryUI in combo with your own HTML and CSS. I'll draw up a fiddle idea ..

Comment: Sure that will be helpful .. Thanks a lot .. :)